# Crash after sleep, ACPI exception

Tags: suspend, crash

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Latitude 7490, and I had hardware problems, so Dell changed the motherboard.
After that, Ubuntu wouldn't start so I had to change the SATA configuration to AHCI instead of the default RAID.
Now Ubuntu boots correctly, but I have another problem: it crashes after resuming from sleep.
Here is the kern.log :

```
# This is when the computer goes to sleep mode.
Feb 16 00:15:17 roquefort kernel: [ 9664.656223] i2c_designware i2c_designware.2: controller timed out
Feb 16 00:15:18 roquefort kernel: [ 9665.680247] i2c_designware i2c_designware.2: controller timed out
Feb 16 00:15:26 roquefort NetworkManager[1321]: <info>  [1613430926.9874] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Feb 16 00:15:26 roquefort NetworkManager[1321]: <info>  [1613430926.9875] manager: sleeping...
Feb 16 00:15:26 roquefort NetworkManager[1321]: <info>  [1613430926.9876] device (enp0s31f6): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [20 10 37]
Feb 16 00:15:27 roquefort kernel: [ 9674.851349] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down
Feb 16 00:15:27 roquefort NetworkManager[1321]: <info>  [1613430927.3505] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Feb 16 00:15:27 roquefort NetworkManager[1321]: <info>  [1613430927.3510] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping') [100 110 37]
Feb 16 00:15:27 roquefort NetworkManager[1321]: <info>  [1613430927.3543] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping') [110 30 37]
Feb 16 00:15:27 roquefort NetworkManager[1321]: <info>  [1613430927.4200] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 5318
Feb 16 00:15:27 roquefort NetworkManager[1321]: <info>  [1613430927.4201] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> done
Feb 16 00:15:27 roquefort kernel: [ 9674.922966] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 10:0d:7f:94:a2:77 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Feb 16 00:15:27 roquefort NetworkManager[1321]: <info>  [1613430927.4321] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Feb 16 00:15:27 roquefort NetworkManager[1321]: <warn>  [1613430927.4393] sup-iface[0x23cd950,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Feb 16 00:15:27 roquefort NetworkManager[1321]: <info>  [1613430927.4394] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Feb 16 00:15:27 roquefort NetworkManager[1321]: <info>  [1613430927.4397] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [30 10 37]
Feb 16 00:15:27 roquefort kernel: [ 9675.499736] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Feb 16 00:15:28 roquefort kernel: [ 9675.499738] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.

# This is what happens when going out of sleep :
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9675.507981] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9675.510202] OOM killer disabled.
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9675.510202] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9675.511607] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9675.845367] e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9675.988898] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.028781] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041454] ACPI: EC: event blocked
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041455] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041455] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041519] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041861] ACPI Exception: AE_BAD_PARAMETER, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20170831/evregion-300)
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041867] 
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041867] Initialized Local Variables for Method [ECR1]:
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041867]   Local0: 000000002de46910 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041871] Initialized Arguments for Method [ECR1]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041871]   Arg0:   00000000efd3600c <Obj>           Integer 000000000000000B
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041874] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV.ECR1, AE_BAD_PARAMETER (20170831/psparse-550)
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041878] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV.ECR2, AE_BAD_PARAMETER (20170831/psparse-550)
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041880] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \ECRW, AE_BAD_PARAMETER (20170831/psparse-550)
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041883] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \ECGD, AE_BAD_PARAMETER (20170831/psparse-550)
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041885] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \NEVT, AE_BAD_PARAMETER (20170831/psparse-550)
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.041888] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66, AE_BAD_PARAMETER (20170831/psparse-550)
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.056370] IRQ 136: no longer affine to CPU1
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.057379] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.086000] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.105807] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.135039] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.156690] IRQ 123: no longer affine to CPU5
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.156697] IRQ 124: no longer affine to CPU5
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.157721] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.188675] IRQ 125: no longer affine to CPU6
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.188685] IRQ 139: no longer affine to CPU6
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.189705] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.220740] IRQ 1: no longer affine to CPU7
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.220749] IRQ 8: no longer affine to CPU7
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.220757] IRQ 9: no longer affine to CPU7
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.220767] IRQ 16: no longer affine to CPU7
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.220775] IRQ 17: no longer affine to CPU7
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.221829] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.229299] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.229420] ACPI: EC: EC started
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.229421] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.233020] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.233082] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.233084] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.235945] microcode: sig=0x806ea, pf=0x80, revision=0xc6
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.238410] microcode: updated to revision 0xe0, date = 2020-06-17
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.238552]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.238848] CPU1 is up
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.238874] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.240471]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.240701] CPU2 is up
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.240736] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.242346]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.242595] CPU3 is up
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.242616] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.242940] microcode: sig=0x806ea, pf=0x80, revision=0xe0
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.243042]  cache: parent cpu4 should not be sleeping
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.243463] CPU4 is up
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.243487] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.243876]  cache: parent cpu5 should not be sleeping
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.244141] CPU5 is up
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.244231] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.244612]  cache: parent cpu6 should not be sleeping
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.244898] CPU6 is up
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.244918] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.245297]  cache: parent cpu7 should not be sleeping
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.245600] CPU7 is up
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.251412] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.306840] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.409256] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.409509] usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.409512] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9676.751862] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9677.004989] acpi LNXPOWER:00: Turning OFF
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9677.005093] OOM killer enabled.
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9677.005094] Restarting tasks ... 
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9677.013271] [drm] RC6 on
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9677.015525] done.
Feb 16 10:06:39 roquefort kernel: [ 9677.139926] thermal thermal_zone8: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Feb 16 10:06:40 roquefort kernel: [ 9677.243150] PM: suspend exit
Feb 16 10:06:40 roquefort NetworkManager[1321]: <info>  [1613466400.0284] manager: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Feb 16 10:06:40 roquefort NetworkManager[1321]: <info>  [1613466400.0284] manager: waking up...
Feb 16 10:06:40 roquefort NetworkManager[1321]: <info>  [1613466400.0286] device (enp0s31f6): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Feb 16 10:06:40 roquefort kernel: [ 9677.260563] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready

# Then I did a hard reboot, because everything was frozen
Feb 16 10:07:19 roquefort kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xe0, date = 2020-06-17
Feb 16 10:07:19 roquefort kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-133-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-024) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)) #137~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 15 02:55:18 UTC 2021 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-133.137~16.04.1-generic 4.15.18)
Feb 16 10:07:19 roquefort kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-133-generic root=UUID=5f5440c0-4ccb-4193-9665-2c0ce17f3b20 ro alx.enable_wol=1 mem_sleep_default=deep i915_bpo.enable_rc6=0 quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

Does anyone have an idea of what can cause the crash/freeze ?
It seems that ACPI has a lot of exceptions and errors but I don't really know what it means.

**EDIT**

I have now updated to Ubuntu 20.04, in hope it would fix the problem, and.... it didn't!
What's worse, now nothing appears in the kern.log, the last message is that it enters 'suspend' mode:

```
Feb 25 21:53:28 roquefort kernel: [  148.551255] rfkill: input handler enabled
Feb 25 21:53:30 roquefort kernel: [  150.672637] rfkill: input handler disabled
Feb 25 21:53:41 roquefort kernel: [  161.520592] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from cc:be:59:7b:9f:ba by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Feb 25 21:53:45 roquefort kernel: [  165.950485] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Feb 26 06:53:28 roquefort kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xe0, date = 2020-06-17
Feb 26 06:53:28 roquefort kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.8.0-44-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-054) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #50~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 10 21:07:30 UTC 2021 (Ubuntu 5.8.0-44.50~20.04.1-generic 5.8.18)
Feb 26 06:53:28 roquefort kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-44-generic root=UUID=88fd1d25-c1e4-4e8c-a49e-46638545555c ro quiet splash crashkernel=512M-:192M vt.handoff=7
Feb 26 06:53:28 roquefort kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Feb 26 06:53:28 roquefort kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Feb 26 06:53:28 roquefort kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Feb 26 06:53:28 roquefort kernel: [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
Feb 26 06:53:28 roquefort kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Feb 26 06:53:28 roquefort kernel: [    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai
```

I'm really lost, and I don't know how to debug that further. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I know you do not want to hear this but after a new motherboard and changing the hard drive interface config I would reinstall from scratch. After saving all your files first of course.

Comment: Yes, I was considering this, and it would give me the opportunity to switch to 20.04 as well. But I don't have the time to backup and reinstall right now, so I was looking for a solution to fix that quickly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it might not be a solution for everyone, but here is mine.
I downgraded to the Linux kernel 5.4, and now I don't have the problem of freezing after sleep, and I also had a lot of problems with Wifi, which I don't have anymore !
So bad news for future readers, I don't have a solution for the AHCI problems in 16.04. It's possible it was also related to having the wrong kernel.

From this [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/ks9lb9/was_the_hwe_kernel_upgrade_to_version_58_supposed/), it seems like a lot of people have been automatically put on kernel 5.8 when doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, and it has broken various things for various people. So I would say I fall in that category.

To be complete, I downgraded to `5.4.101` because the discussion says that 5.4 is the GA (General Availability) version that servers should use (i.e. it's more stable).

As a side note, I discovered the very helpful GUI *Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer* (`mainline` package).